# read() return "incorrect" value

Tags: c, linux

```
while(  rd = read(fd1, buf, 512) != 0)
{
    len += rd;
    if(readed < 0) 
    perror("read: ");
}
```

MAN pages says, that read() returns number of read bytes, but in my case this code returns number of blocks(depends of 3rd argument) or number of iterations. for example, I have file with 36 symbols and this code returns 1, when all symbols normally read, if I change 512 to 4, it will return 9, and so on. Please correct me and this code to return number of bytes which read with 512 size blocks

Comment: Yes, thanks to all. I`m forget, that operations processing from right to left, and != have higher priority than =

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rd = read(fd1, buf, 512) != 0
```

means

```
rd = (read(fd1, buf, 512) != 0)
```

The result of `!=` is always either `0` or `1`.

You probably meant

```
while ((rd = read(fd1, buf, 512)) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect use of brackets,
Pl. change your code like below. Hope It will give you the correct result.

```
while(  (rd = read(fd1, buf, 512)) != 0)
{
    len += rd;
    if(rd < 0) 
    perror("read: ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set th rd value outside of while loop condition?
Without more bracket i think the Setting and testing the value section in the while condition is not correct.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer... Try to improve it!